# Sending mail from PHP gives Unrouteable address

Tags: php, email, smtp, exim4

I have a Debian server running PHP and Exim4 (among other things of course).
The PHP application is sending 1000s of emails every day all of which work fine, however I now have a new customer and my PHP/Exim4 has trouble sending to this account.

PS I added the --at-- to stop crawlers finding the addresses.

1. I checked the exim4 logs and found this:

> ```
> 2014-04-02 08:48:10 1WV7TW-0001Em-Od <= support --at-- sobs.com.au H=localhost [127.0.0.1] P=esmtp S=1215 
> 2014-04-02 08:48:11 1WV7TW-0001Em-Od ** az --at-- mentonegrammmar: Unrouteable address 
> 2014-04-02 08:48:11 1WV7TW-0001Em-Od Completed
> ```

1. I then checked the routing in exim4 using:

   exim -d -f support --at-- sobs.com.au -bt az --at-- mentonegrammar

> ```
> Exim version 4.80 uid=0 gid=0 pid=12506 D=fbb95cfd
> Berkeley DB: Berkeley DB 5.1.29: (October 25, 2011)
> Support for: crypteq iconv() IPv6 GnuTLS move_frozen_messages DKIM
> Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch cdb dbm dbmjz dbmnz dnsdb dsearch nis nis0 passwd
> Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
> Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
> Transports: appendfile/maildir/mailstore autoreply lmtp pipe smtp
> Fixed never_users: 0
> Size of off_t: 8
> Compiler: GCC [4.7.2]
> Library version: GnuTLS: Compile: 2.12.20
> Runtime: 2.12.20
> Library version: PCRE: Compile: 8.31
> Runtime: 8.30 2012-02-04
> Total 13 lookups
> WHITELIST_D_MACROS: "OUTGOING"
> TRUSTED_CONFIG_LIST: "/etc/exim4/trusted_configs"
> changed uid/gid: forcing real = effective
> uid=0 gid=0 pid=12506
> auxiliary group list: none
> seeking password data for user "uucp": cache not available
> getpwnam() succeeded uid=10 gid=10
> changed uid/gid: calling tls_validate_require_cipher
> uid=101 gid=103 pid=12507
> auxiliary group list: none
> tls_validate_require_cipher child 12507 ended: status=0x0
> configuration file is /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
> log selectors = 00000ffc 00612001
> trusted user
> admin user
> seeking password data for user "mail": cache not available
> getpwnam() succeeded uid=8 gid=8
> user name "root" extracted from gecos field "root"
> originator: uid=0 gid=0 login=root name=root
> sender address = root --at-- ds6419.hostname.net.au
> Address testing: uid=0 gid=103 euid=0 egid=103
> Testing az --at-- mentonegrammar
> Considering az --at-- mentonegrammar
> routing az --at-- mentonegrammar
> -------- hubbed_hosts router --------
> local_part=az domain=mentonegrammar
> checking domains
> expansion of "${if exists{/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts}{partial-lsearch;/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts}fail}"
> forced failure: assume not in this list
> hubbed_hosts router skipped: domains mismatch
> -------- dnslookup_relay_to_domains router --------
> local_part=az domain=mentonegrammar
> checking domains
> search_open: dsearch "/etc/exim4/virtual"
> search_find: file="/etc/exim4/virtual"
> key="mentonegrammar" partial=-1 affix=NULL starflags=0
> LRU list:
> 5/etc/exim4/virtual
> End
> internal_search_find: file="/etc/exim4/virtual"
> type=dsearch key="mentonegrammar"
> file lookup required for mentonegrammar
> in /etc/exim4/virtual
> lookup failed
> mentonegrammar.net in "@:localhost:dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual"? no (end of list)
> mentonegrammar.net in "empty"? no (end of list)
> mentonegrammar.net in "! +local_domains : +relay_to_domains"? no (end of list)
> dnslookup_relay_to_domains router skipped: domains mismatch
> -------- dnslookup router --------
> local_part=az domain=mentonegrammar
> checking domains
> cached no match for +local_domains
> cached lookup data = NULL
> mentonegrammar in "! +local_domains"? yes (end of list)
> R: dnslookup for az@mentonegrammar
> calling dnslookup router
> dnslookup router called for az --at-- mentonegrammar
> domain = mentonegrammar
> DNS lookup of mentonegrammar (MX) succeeded
> DNS lookup of mail.mentonegrammar (AAAA) gave NO_DATA
> returning DNS_NODATA
> DNS lookup of mail.mentonegrammar (A) succeeded
> 58.96.103.231 in "0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8 : 192.168.0.0/16 :172.16.0.0/12 : 10.0.0.0/8 : 169.254.0.0/16 :255.255.255.255"? no
> (end of list)
> fully qualified name = mentonegrammar
> host_find_bydns yield = HOST_FOUND (2); returned hosts:
> mail.mentonegrammar 58.96.103.231 MX=5
> set transport remote_smtp
> queued for remote_smtp transport: local_part = az
> domain = mentonegrammar
> errors_to=NULL
> domain_data=NULL localpart_data=NULL
> routed by dnslookup router
> envelope to: az --at-- mentonegrammar
> transport: remote_smtp
> host mail.mentonegrammar [58.96.103.231] MX=5
> search_tidyup called
> =============== Exim pid=12506 terminating with rc=0 ===============
> az --at-- mentonegrammar
> router = dnslookup, transport = remote_smtp
> host mail.mentonegrammar [58.96.103.231] MX=5
> ```

This looks as though the routing is working perfectly.  I tried the application email again and still get the Unrouteable address error.

1. Then I tried a command line email from the same server.

   echo "Test message" | mail -s "Test message" az --at-- mentonegrammar

This email worked and arrived as required, but the email from my PHP application still fails.

1. I checked the application:

> ```
> $mime = new Mail_mime();
> $formattedHeaders = $mime->headers($headers);
> $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
> $content = $mime->get(array('html_charset' => 'utf-8'));
> $smtp = Mail::factory("smtp", array());
> $result = $smtp->send($headers["To"], $formattedHeaders, $content);
> ```

1. As mentioned there are 1000s of emails being successfully sent by this server and application.
2. The IT at Mentone Grammar haven't indicated any problems receiving any other emails.

In summary, I keep coming back to the 'Unrouteable address' error in the exim4 log, and the debug output indicating that the address is routable.  I can't help thinking there is some problem with the Exim4 config - but I just don't know.

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: exim questions may do better on server fault: http://serverfault.com

Comment: Is there a simple way to transfer this to the ServerFault area?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the 'm's.  The original entry from the application has 'mentonegrammmar' where as my later testing has 'mentonegrammar'.  My browser was remembering the incorrect entry for the application and auto-filling the form, and I didn't notice.

Thanks to krisFR for his answer in ServerFault.